# Jest exception "cannot find module" with spfx solutions

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, jestjs, spfx

I have written some unit test cases to test my SPFx web part using Jest and Enzyme. However, when I ran the tests, I encountered a "Cannot find module" exception on the import statement.

See below error details -

```
Cannot find module './httpClient/HttpClient' from 'node_modules/@microsoft/sp-http/lib-commonjs/index.js'
  Require stack:
  node_modules/@microsoft/sp-http/lib-commonjs/index.js
  src/common/services/sp-services.ts
  src/webparts/TestWebpart/components/custom/Services.ts
  src/webparts/TestWebpart/components/TestWebpart.tsx
  src/webparts/TestWebpart/test/TestWebpart.test.tsx

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@microsoft/sp-http/lib-commonjs/index.js:14:20)
```

Import file path and verison of react and jest also fine.  see below dev dependecies -

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.5",
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.7": "0.2.3",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.12.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.12.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules": "1.12.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "1.12.1",
    "@types/enzyme": "3.10.13",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.1",
    "@types/react": "16.9.36",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.8",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.7",
    "gulp": "~4.0.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-junit": "16.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.11",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.5"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I blogged about it some time ago. You can find the article [here](https://mgwdevcom.wordpress.com/2023/05/29/state-of-spfx-unit-testing-in-2023/). There is a link to a sample with full setup.

Long story short - SPFx is not ready to be run in jest runtime, so You have to mock most spfx libraries using jest.mock to prevent loading it from node_modules.